Do Haars Cascades work well when subjects don't share common features?
My understanding is that haars cascades work well when subjects share common features, like faces.
Do they still provide good results when subjects to be identified do not share common features?

TL;DR:
No.
Haar cascades are computationally efficient and work well for detecting objects with consistent, shared features. However, they perform poorly when subjects lack common features due to their reliance on fixed feature sets. Modern methods like CNNs are better suited for diverse and dynamic object detection tasks.

Haar cascades, introduced in a seminal paper by Viola and Jones (2001), were a revolutionary advancement in the field of computer vision - in particular, object detection - by enabling efficient and rapid identification of objects in images. They rely on Haar-like features, which are rectangular patterns of contrast evaluated using integral images (also known as Summed-area tables), which allow features to be computed at any scale or location in near-constant time. These features were selected using AdaBoost by Viola and Jones and it remains the typical way of selection (Ghosh and Swarnalatha, 2021). AdaBoost constructs a cascaded classifier that focuses computational effort on promising regions, achieving high detection rates with low computational cost. For example, the original system demonstrated a 95% detection rate with a false-positive rate of 1 in 14,084 for frontal face detection.
Haar cascades are most effective when applied to objects with consistent, well-defined features, such as human faces, which exhibit predictable patterns of brightness and contrast (eg., darker eye sockets relative to cheeks). However, their performance degrades considerably in scenarios where target objects lack shared features, such as detecting non-standard objects or those with high intra-class variability. The fixed feature set, trained on specific positive and negative samples, limits their ability to generalise to more diverse objects or complex transformations. Although multi-scale detection addresses scale variability to some extent, the method struggles with intra-class variability, orientation changes, and challenging lighting conditions.
These limitations are exacerbated in dynamic or unconstrained environments. Ghosh and Swarnalatha (2021) emphasised that Haar cascades perform poorly when common features are absent and highlighted their sensitivity to differing pose and lighting variations. In contrast, modern deep learning methods, such as convolutional neural networks (CNNs), learn hierarchical features directly from data, enabling them to handle complex intra-class variability and outperform Haar cascades across diverse detection tasks. While CNNs require significant computational resources and large datasets, their adaptability makes them suitable for contemporary object detection challenges. Other models that could used include transformer-based models, graph neural networks and boosted ensembles.
Summing up: Haar cascades are computationally efficient for detecting objects with consistent features, but their applicability is limited when commonalities are absent. Alternatives, such as YOLO and Faster R-CNN, should provide superior adaptability and accuracy.
References

Ghosh, G., & Swarnalatha, K. S. (2021). A review on object detection using Haar cascades and its limitations. In Shetty, N. R., & Shetty, N. (Eds.), Advances in Artificial Intelligence and Data Engineering. Springer, 341-355.
Viola, P., & Jones, M. (2001). Rapid object detection using a boosted cascade of simple features. Proceedings of the 2001 IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 1, 511-518.

